# How to automate Unix bin install answer interactive prompts

Tags: shell

Trying to automate to answer interactive prompts
I tried using `printf`, and `echo` it seems didn't work...

```
echo "o 3 Y N Y N Y Y N" | ./xxxx.bin 
printf "o 3 Y N Y N Y Y N" | ./xxxx.bin
```

Here is the example of prompts

```
This will install Software 1.1 on your computer.
OK [o, Enter], Cancel [c]
o

Choose the appropriate installation or upgrade option.
Please choose one of the following:
Express Install (use default settings) [1], Custom Install (recommended for advanced users) [2], Upgrade an existing installation [3, Enter]
3
```

etc

Comment: You should use expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`printf "o\n3\nY\nN\nY\nN\nY\nY\nN\n" | { ./xxxx.bin ; }`

Comment: Wrap `./xxxx.bin` in `{...}` if he continues to have problems, it should work as you have written.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Tnx, It's odd that single command bracket wrapper seems like it shouldn't do anything, but I recall testing it with something or other similar in the past and that it worked.  It's a parsing order modifier IIRC.

Comment: It's hard to tell how the questioner is reading in his script, but the `{...}` will provide an independent block for the handling of `stdin`. If he is just calling `read` in the script, he shouldn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to feed a command/answer list, and you may maintain the input easily.

```
./xxxx.bin << EOF
o
3
Y
N
Y
N
Y
Y
N
EOF
```